# Two foreign key condition required for same table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-key-relationship

[image: ERD]

I attached a simple diagram of my old database.

In this design

- There is a many-to-many relationship between the two tables **T** and **P** represented by table **TP**.
- The relationship table **TP** has one-to-many relationship with table **D**

Now, There Is some changes in the requirements, that **T** itself could has many (**D**)s.

How to make these new foreign key condition in table **D** in addition to the old one (**TP** to **D**).

I mean, Is it possible to link **T.[Id]** to **D.[T]** in addition to the link **TP.[ T , P ]** to **D.[ T , P ]**?

How to solve my new requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could put a foreign key reference from table T into table D. It will be a one-to-many relationship just as the table T to table TP relationship.

I dont understand why you want to have a FK reference to table T in table D though. Currently you could join T to TP to D to get the rows in table D that are related to a row in table T.

Comment: If I just added T to D relation. Then, insertion new row to D may break the TP to D condition. is it wrong?

Comment: @Lio - Yes that is right, but that would also break your DB table design now as well as if you were to add the T to D relationship. If you put a new row in D you would break the TP to D relationship currently and with the extra FK relationship I am suggesting.

Comment: What do you think if I just make D.[P] nullable? could that make sense?
I'm saying that because sql-sever seems to be accepting it.
I'm confused now.

Comment: @Lio - You could make the FK reference nullable and that would make sense...if a row in T may not have a corresponding row in D and the FK reference between T and TP is nullable.

Comment: Thank you @GWines, I added an answer and hope it gives some idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is straightforward. Just add a new column to D linking to T. Notice that, if I´ve got this right, the T from D.[T,P] may be not the same as the T from D.[T]

Comment: that is mean I could not use the same column D.[T] for the two relations. right?

Comment: Because they may be (probably) two different T's actually in the same D. Think of TP as just another entity. Imagine your diagram just like 2 relationships: to T and X. X can be anything, even TP. Suppose for example that TP had instead a surrogate key K (autoincrement, sequence, whatever) and a unique clause for T and P. Wouldn´t be the same if D has a foreign key to K and to T at the same time?

Comment: Thank you @Leonardo.
Yes, it seems to be the same situation.
I don't know why sql-server allow to make this combination, even it could not be used.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you to follow my example. Instead of creating a composite foreign key, use a surrogate key K in TP, add a unique clause for {TP.T,TP.P} and then add two not null clauses, one for TP.T and another for TP.P. Then D can have 2 foreign keys, one for T and another for K.

Comment: I added an answer. could you please review it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

- Making **D.[T]** Nullable.
- Adding the new foreign key constrain to table **D** (**T.[Id]** to **D.[T]**).

Now,

If new row inserted into **D** table so that the **P** component value set to **NULL**, then just the constrain **T to D** will be checked.

If the new row has it's **P** component set to value defer from **NULL**, then the two constrains **T to D** and **TP to D** will be checked.